# Extract information using jQuery from table and package into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I got a task which I am asked to extract several information (using jQuery) from a table when a user click submit and package into JSON object which will be stored in a database.

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ek30dgt9/2/

Here's my HTML code:

```
    <body>

    <div >

    <table border=1px>

  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Description</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Feedback</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody style="border-top : 1px solid black" id = "1">
    <tr>
        <td class="partition"><label class="label">Title:</label><label class="label ">A</label></td>
        <td class="sip" style="border-left:none"><label class="label">Author:</label><label class="label">James</label></td>
        <td rowspan="4"><input type="checkbox"><label class="label" style="padding-left:0px">Ordinary</label></td>
        <td rowspan="4"><input type="checkbox"><label class="label" style="padding-left:0px">Interesting</label></td>
        <td rowspan="4"><input type="checkbox"><label class="label" style="padding-left:0px">Amazing</label></td>
        <td rowspan="4"><textarea maxlength="180" class="animated" id="usercomment" name="comment" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;  height: 80px; width:280px;">The book is ..........</textarea></td>
        <td rowspan="4" align="center">Adam<br><button class="label label-primary">Submit</button></td>
        <td rowspan="4" align="center">Feedback Goes Here<br></td>
            <td rowspan="4" align="center"><br>No Feedback Yet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="def"><label class="label">Genre:</label><label class="label">Fiction</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="path"><label class="label label-primary" style="margin-left:5px">BookURL</label><label class="label label-primary " style="margin-left:40px">DownloadLink</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="path"><a style="display:none">www.ddd.com/bookurl</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have no ideas on how to extract all the info using jQuery.

My JSON object has to be like this:

```
{
"tbodyid":"1",
"title":"A",
"author":"James",
"genre":"fiction",
"bookurl":"www.bllllll.com",
"downloadlink":"www.zzzz.com",
"source":
{
    "selection":"library",
    "checked":"true",
}
"comment":"comment_goes_here",
"user":"Adam",
"feedback":"feedback_from_lecturer_goes_here",
"status":"no feedback yet",
}
```

p/s: Users are allowed to select multiple options for the source. e.g: Library and Ebook.

Comment: your html is invalid. you should use the form tag and specify wich method you will be using(get or post)

Comment: Something missing here...how is that html generated in the first place? You don't appear to have any user input other than checkbox. Can bind the original data to the rows

Comment: @AlexB this question has nothing to do with parsing a url

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id attribute to the elements you need to extract:

```
<tr>
    <td class="partition"><label class="label" id='title'>Title:</label><label class="label ">A</label></td>
    <td class="sip" style="border-left:none"><label class="label" id='author'>Author:</label><label class="label">James</label></td>
...
</td>
```

And then, using JQuery:

```
function foo() {
    return {
        "title": $("#title").html(),
        "author": $("#author").html()
        ...
    }
}
```